# Setting a number as element name in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, wso2

In my xslt I have a variable 'number'. I want to use this value as an element's name in my final xml output. How can I achieve this?

**XSLT**

```
<input>
    <xsl:variable name="number" value="658976"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$number}">Hello</xsl:element>
</<input>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<input>
   <658976>Hello</658976>
</input>
```

Comment: Even the StackOverflow syntax highlighting code can see that this isn't XML!

Answer (score 2):

An XML element's name cannot start with a digit: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameStartChar

Comment: Is there any workaround for a digit to be used as an element name?

Comment: If you find such workaround, the result will no longer be an XML document and any conforming parser will reject it. Why would you need such thing? Note that you can easily produce an element such as `<_658976>Hello</_658976>`.

Comment: I was able to using a character with the number earlier too, just wanted to check if it was possible without one.
Thanks for letting me know!